# React-Bootstrap-Table Pagination Not Working

Tags: reactjs

I've used React-Bootstrap-Table Pagination.. I browserifed my jsx file and it is showing the pagination symbol but I'm not able to change the size.

Comment: What you have tried so far? put some code here

Comment: put some example or code to be more clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the similar issue, after including jquery reference, pagination was working fine.This issue has been already reported on github repo of react bootstrap table, they provided the solution for that, kindly check the page and see at what step you are missing something.

https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/issues/338

https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/issues/87

Please comment on this if you want any other details.

Comment: I was not aware about including jquery dependency. So after including its working fine. Thank You !!!